# Permission denied error when i try to start appengine php server

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm trying to start GAE php local server and i get a "[Error 5] permission denied" error (Acceso denegado). I tried this on two different PC's
both with windows 7 (One is home edition and the other is enterprise edition) and always the same problem.

On both cases i'm a user with administrator privileges and i've follow the instructions from the helloworld example but no luck. I switched off IIS server to avoid conflicts with the standar port.

Here's my start server command line:

```
C:/Users/alalarcon/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path="C:/Users/alalarcon/php-5.4.15" "C:/Users/alalarcon/helloworld/"
```

And that's the result from the console:

```
C:\Users\alalarcon\google_appengine>dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path="C:/Users/alalarcon/php-5.4.15" "C:/Users/alalarcon/helloworld/"
WARNING  2013-05-30 10:03:02,525 api_server.py:329] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-05-30 10:03:02,539 api_server.py:153] Starting API server at: http://localhost:63819
INFO     2013-05-30 10:03:02,545 dispatcher.py:164] Starting server "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alalarcon\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\alalarcon\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alalarcon\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\server.py", line 1232, in _loop_adjusting_instances
    self._adjust_instances()
  File "C:\Users\alalarcon\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\server.py", line 1209, in _adjust_instances
    self._add_instance(permit_warmup=True)
  File "C:\Users\alalarcon\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\server.py", line 1087, in _add_instance
    expect_ready_request=perform_warmup)
  File "C:\Users\alalarcon\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\php_runtime.py", line 195, in new_instance
    self._check_environment(php_executable_path)
  File "C:\Users\alalarcon\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\php_runtime.py", line 138, in _check_environment
    env={})
  File "C:\Users\alalarcon\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\safe_subprocess.py", line 61, in start_process
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\alalarcon\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Users\alalarcon\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Acceso denegado

INFO     2013-05-30 10:03:02,551 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

Any help is apreciated, thanks.

Comment: Finally solved. First of all, --php_executable_path parameter must include "php-cgi.exe" file name and php.ini must exists on the php folder.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On **Windows**, you have to say the **ABSOLUTE PATH to PHP** within the **executable name**! Like this:

`python dev_appserver.py --skip_sdk_update_check=yes --port=8080
--admin_port=8000 --php_executable_path=C:\xampp\php\php-cgi.exe C:\www\projects\your_project_name`

ps: run this command being on the "google_appengine" path.